# iPhone application response to network connection

Tags: iphone

I am making application which uses connection with server through internet.

In my application i want to check if internet is available or not when application starts and during application as well. when there is no internet access then it has to show some alert to tell user.
Thanks for any suggestion in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sample code called Reachability from apple can help you. see the URL below

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html